# SNMP commands from a Linux server

Tags: networking, snmp

I want to probe a device in SNMP from a Linux server. I need to know all the commands that are valid from the server(SNMP Manager). Can anyone provide me with the link where I can study all the commands? I have searched a lot but I am able to find only few commands that can used to probe the device.
Thank You!

Comment: Had you see http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Tutorials ?  That page is very informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to SNMP rfc section 4.1.1 on-wards to see the basic SNMP Request PDU's. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1157#section-4.1.1

There are multiple tools free and licensed that you could use to probe SNMP Agent(server). One such command line tool is net-snmp based. Refer the following link for the same.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/snmpcmd.1.html

The above reference has man pages related to snmpget/snmpwalk to get you started.

Hope it helps!